# node-gyp configure error on win 8.1 x64

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

- Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012 for Windows Desktop Express version works well
- installed python 2.7.3
- `PYTHON` and `PYTHONPATH` path variable has setted

error thrown when I ran `npm install bcrypt`

and I tried on node `0.10.2 64`,`0.12.2 32`,`0.12.2 64` but got the same error

```
C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn E:\Environment\python27 ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
gyp ERR! stack     at child_process.js:1144:20
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Where is Python installed? It looks like it's trying to find the interpreter in `E:\Environment\python27` (or use that as the executable).

Comment: @robertklep Python is installed in `E:\Environment\python27`.I'm not familiar with Python. But `python.exe` is under the folder,and I can run it in command line like `node`.

Comment: Try this: `npm config set python E:\Environment\python27\python.exe`